# Why su command takes to long in nested Debian LXD containers?

Tags: linux, debian, su, lxd

I observed that the command `su` takes too long (30 seconds) when it is executed in a LXD Debian container that is nested into an Ubuntu LXD container.  This overhead does not occur Debian containers that are not nested, nor in Ubuntu containers nested into an Ubuntu container. Does anyone have any explanation for this? Next I describe how to reproduce this issue.

## Setup

I have set up LXD containers in an Ubuntu 18.04 machine to use nested containers (as is described in https://ubuntu.com/blog/nested-containers-in-lxd). I use the system apt packages (`lxd` and `lxd-client`) to install LXD. Then, I created two containers as follows:

```sh
lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 c1 -c security.nesting=true
lxc launch images:debian/10 c2
```

Then, inside container c1, I created two nested containers:

```sh
lxd init
lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 c3
lxc launch images:debian/10 c4
```

In the Debian containers, I created non-root user `debian` with the following command:

```sh
adduser --home /home/debian --gecos Debian --disabled-password debian
```

In Ubuntu containers is not needed to create a non-root user because the `ubuntu` user is already defined.

## Measuring how long `su` takes

For each container I measure the time required for the command `su` with the following commands (where `user` is either `ubuntu` or `debian`):

```sh
time pwd
time su $user -c pwd
```

It is expected that the second command takes more time due to the overhead of the `su` command.  In all cases this overhead is around 59 milliseconds, except for container `c4` (i.e., for the Debian container inside the Ubuntu container) where the overhead is around 30 seconds.

Comment: Don't know if related, but for me this is even the case on a non-nested Debian container (running on a Debian host), although "only" 35 seconds.

Comment: Did you try `strace su "$user" -c pwd`. In my case it seems to timeout polling some socket (probably DBus). If I read the log correctly it is `/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`. Would be interesting if my case is related to yours. It could be related to PAM for instance.

Comment: Indeed: After disabling `session optional pam_systemd.so`  in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` (included by `/etc/pam/su.conf`) it works fast as light :)
Let's see if you can hunt it down. (Btw. I got a bunch of related logs hinting to isues with `systemd-logind` in the journal as well.)

Comment: Thanks @doak, just commenting that line in the configuration makes it fast!

Comment: Nice. Answer should be added. dbus is the reason indeed. Probably because of the unprivileged GID/UID difference. Commenting works, consider add it as a workaround answer.

Comment: @goterugu, good suggestion! I will include that workaround answer.